# Arrange .xhtml files in separate folder in war - JSF2

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces and JSF2 . All my `.xhtml` files are dumped in the `war` folder. Is it possible to arrange them in separate folder? When I tried, `.xhtml` didn't get loaded.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your web.xml file.
make sure the Faces Servlet's url-pattern points to the new folder's path. 
Or simply change the url-pattern to *.xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

if you change the location of XHTML you also need to change the code that is associated with its path

For example : returning viewId

```
return "viewPerson"
```